# Generate C# class using mgmtclassgen command for IISWebInfo (WMI)

Tags: c#, command-line, wmi

How generate C# class using mgmtclassgen  command for IISWebInfo ??

I test like this:

> C:\Temp>mgmtclassgen Win32_LogicalDisk
>   /n root\cimv2 /l CS /p c:\disk.cs
>   Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Version
>   3.5.21022.8 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>   Generating Code for WMI Class
>   Win32_LogicalDisk ... Code Generated
>   Successfully!!!!
>
> C:\Temp>mgmtclassgen IISWebInfo /n
>   root\cimv2 /l CS /p c:\disk2.cs
>   Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Version
>   3.5.21022.8 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>   Getting the given class Failed
>
> C:\Temp>mgmtclassgen IIsWebInfo /n
>   root\cimv2 /l CS /p c:\disk2.cs
>   Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Version
>   3.5.21022.8 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>   Getting the given class Failed
>
> C:\Temp>mgmtclassgen IIsWebInfo /n
>   root\MicrosoftIISv2 /l CS /p
>   c:\disk2.cs Microsoft (R) .NET
>   Framework Version 3.5.21022.8
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. 
>   All rights reserved. Errors
>   Occurred!!!! Reason : Espacio de
>   nombres no válido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [`IIsWebInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524869%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class is present in the `root\MicrosoftIISv2` namespace. so  you must check which this namespace exist in your system.

this error message `Errors Occurred!!!! Reason : Espacio de nombres no válido` means which the namespace does not exist in your system.

you can found more information in this link

- [`Connecting to the IIS WMI Provider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525808%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: I think it's not present in XP, but win2003 is present. Win2008 I dont know